# exchanging data through pipes between C# and cPython

Tags: c#, python, ipc, pipe

I have what (I think) is a relatively simple task. I have to provide to some C# app a way to invoke my Python app and pass some data for processing and receive back the results at the end of the Python task (both are GUI apps.

I thought that pipes would do the job nicely with the C# side creating a named pipe thus

```
    using (NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer =
    new NamedPipeServerStream("Demo", PipeDirection.InOut))      

    {// Wait for a client to connect

         pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
```

the app can p/invoke the python app passing the name of the pipe in sysarg, etc.

on the python side, once the pipe name is known and using win32pipe something like

```
message = 'a test'
pipeName = '\\\\.\\pipe\\Demo'

win32pipe.CallNamedPipe(pipeName, message, 4096 , win32pipe.NMPWAIT_WAIT_FOREVER)
```

should work.

What happens is that the C# detects the incoming connection but the python side "crashes" on an infamous error:(87,'CallNmaedPipe",'The parameter is incorrect').

I'm no expert on pipes and am at loss to see what might be wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

CallNamedPipe requires a pipe that is created in PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE; your C# code creates a pipe in PIPE_TYPE_BYTE. So you either need to create a pipe in message mode in C# (using a constructor that expects PipeTransmissionMode), or use WriteFile to put data into the pipe.