# How can I send plaintext commands to c# class is running on win7 which has a scriptengine?

Tags: c#, python, python-2.7, ipython

I have a c# class that is running as an engine (don't ask what or why, just think of it as another optimization library) on windows 7.

I don't speak c#, but I can read the API docs and create single commands which should be possible to send to the c# library's scriptEngine.

Here are some examples:

Example 1:

```
var someunit = context.CreateUnit("someunit", 10)
someunit.Volume = 1;
someunit.Weight = 3;
```

Example 2:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 14; i++ )
{
    context.CreateEvent(someunit, currentTime.AddDays(i), SpaceShip, 100);
    context.CreateEvent(someunit, currentTime.AddDays(i), SpaceShip, 100);
    context.CreateEvent(someunit, currentTime.AddDays(i), SpaceShip, 100);
}
```

Example 3:

```
while (true)
{
    if (Engine.State == Engine.Finished)
    {
     //Do something when engine stops
        break;
    }
}
```

IPython does 98% of what I need to do, but on this one I'm stuck. Is there some way I can use a `connectObject` or `import dotNetMagic` so I can generate these strings using python syntax and interact with the c# scriptEngine?

*Afterthought*: If the scriptEngine can be avoided and I can communicate directly with the API then that would be double bonus.

Comment: It helps if you say what Class/Engine you are using and what do you want it to do, The short answer for your question is no, not without doing code in C# witch you cant.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to communicate between the two systems using pipes. Both C# and Python support them.

See this link for a discussion about pipes: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9eb8804-46e7-4207-b7fc-fc68f965566f/communication-between-python-and-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Also see this SO: [exchanging data through pipes between C# and cPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138124/exchanging-data-through-pipes-between-c-sharp-and-cpython)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but it seems you either want [some sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009213/c-sharp-ironpython-interop-with-shared-c-sharp-class-library) of [interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367976/calling-a-c-sharp-library-from-python), which looks ugly to me. :-)

You might think about doing some UDP or [TCP communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819667/using-python-to-send-an-image-over-tcp-to-c-sharp-server) between the two. This is a pretty standard method. I think this is the route I would explore first.